# spread betting platform, where to start?

Tags: finance, computational-finance

I wish to develop a simple spread betting platform for my masters degree,the trouble is there is not a lot of material on the internet. Can someone please point me in the right direction? For example do I need to create an account with a broker? What are the available technologies I can use?

thanks in advance

Comment: No, we cannot. StackOverflow helps you with implementation problems, as a master student you should do the research yourself.

Comment: From the [help/on-topic]: Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. A "point in the right direction" would clearly be a recommendation for an off-site resource, so your question is off-topic here. Good luck.